# Chat not pinging when name is too short

Tags: bug, chat, ping, reply

As seen [HERE](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/11049946#11049946), pings aren't registered when they use less than 3 characters.

His name "C X" *is* 3 characters, but because of the space and the way spaces are removed for pings it doesn't seem possible to ping him unless it's a direct reply.

Comment: Why can't he just change his user name? I'm assuming he can't be notified in comments, either. (*Hmmm, that gives me an idea...*)

Comment: He already knows. But why have him change his name? It's a bug in the way the system is setup and it should be fixed by either changing the way pings work, or changing the requirements for usernames.

Comment: From experience...  He could go with "C.X.".  :)

Comment: @A.M. I hope you're just joking because of your own name :P.
This needs fixed though. We can't just treat the symptoms, it needs to be fixed from the core.

Comment: @Jhawinsss I agree that seems like a hole that needs to be patched.  I just thought I would point out a solution that would work for "C X" *now* (message notifications work for me) and be barely a change of identity at all.  Yes, though...kind of funny that we both have two-letter user names.

Comment: Whoever downvoted needs to explain why.